# How to concat each i-row of one 2D array with each i-row of another 2D arrays

Tags: multidimensional-array, 2d

In my java application i have a method which return me three 2D arrays .All the same size of rows and columns . For example let suppose those are my three 2D arrays which my method return

a=[2,4,5,18
      9,4,1,7
      14,67,90,2]

b=[34,23,1,9
     12,5,9,0
     14,67,8,1]

c=[2,68,1,1
     3,7,0,11
    23,45,5,5]

Now what i want to achieve is ti create another method and to return again three 2D arrays but now first 2D array should have the first row from each 2D arrays above, the second row should have the second rows of each 2D arrays above and so for the third new 2D array.

I am thinking all day how to do it but i still did not figure it out any way how to achieve it. I will really appreciate if somebody suggest me how to do it or better to post some line of codes so i will have any idea how to proceed later

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to write a method in which you supply your three original arrays and row length for each array(I'd suggest writing a different method for each new row array, keeps code cleaner) and then just iterate through each supplied array.

public int [ ] [ ] newRowOneArray(int rowLength, int[ ][ ] a, int[ ][ ] b, int[ ][ ] c){

```
 int returnArray[] [] = new int[3][rowLength]; //new 2d array 

 for(int i=0; i<rowLength; i++){
      returnArray[0][i] = a[0][i]; //place a row one in new row 1
 }

 for(int i=0; i<rowLength; i++){
      returnArray[1][i] = b[0][i]; //place b row one in new row 2

 }

 for(int i=0; i<rowLength; i++){
      returnArray[2][i] = c[0][i]; //place c row one in new row 3

 }

 return returnArray;
```

}

Then you could write similar methods for your other two new arrays. Just change the row value (e.g. a[1][ i ] for row two) for each new method corresponding with a new row

Comment: I am confused why you are giving as a return type of the method above one dimensional array rather than two dimensional  type ? I think its probably wrong typing by you because when you return , you return a 2D array . Am i right

Comment: Yeah it should be a 2d array that is returned. My return type looks right to me, but maybe I mistyped.

Comment: This is perfectly right but what i really want is that i have n - 2D arrays not only a , b , c and also k rows for each n - 2D arrays , so i can not put as argument of the method int [] [] a, int [] [] b , int [][]c since i will have more . Is there any way how to do it ? :(

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but you're going to have a lot of overhead. You could possibly keep an arraylist of all of your arrays and at the same time keep track of the number of rows and length of rows in variables as well (this is assuming that all of your arrays have the same number of rows and columns like you stated in your question). Then your for loops would need to create new 2d arrays for the number of rows contained in your passed variable with row length as your other passed variable. Then place all of your new 2d arrays into a new arraylist to be returned by your method.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple class to help you out. It takes in a list of matrices[i][m][n] where i (numMatrices) = m (rows) = n (cols) and returns a same sized 3-dimensional array with all rows k put into matrix k at row index = matrix index.

```
public class MatrixManipulator {

    public int[][][] combine(int[][][] matrices) {

        // We are making a lot of assumptions here by not checking
        // that dimension are equal (cubic for this problem)
        final int numMatrices = matrices.length, numRows = matrices[0].length, numColumns = matrices[0][0].length;

        int[][][] newMatrices = new int[numMatrices][numRows][numColumns];

        for (int i = 0; i < numMatrices; ++i) {
            for (int m = 0; m < numRows; ++m) {
                for (int n = 0; n < numColumns; ++n) {
                    newMatrices[i][m][n] = matrices[n][m][i];
                }
            }
        }
        return newMatrices;
    }

    public void printMatrices(int[][][] matrices) {
        final int numMatrices = matrices.length, numRows = matrices[0].length, numColumns = matrices[0][0].length;

        for (int i = 0; i < numMatrices; ++i) {
            System.out.println("Matrix " + (i + 1));
            for (int m = 0; m < numRows; ++m) {
                for (int n = 0; n < numColumns; ++n) {
                    System.out.print(matrices[i][n][m]);
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Before calling combine()

```
Matrix 1
111
222
333

Matrix 2
111
222
333

Matrix 3
111
222
333
```

After calling combine()

```
Matrix 1
111
111
111

Matrix 2
222
222
222

Matrix 3
333
333
333
```

Keep in mind that my implementation of matrices is stored as a list of columns. For some people it may be more intuitive to store a list of rows. In order for a list of rows to work you just need to change this one line from:

```
newMatrices[i][m][n] = matrices[n][m][i];
```

to

```
newMatrices[i][m][n] = matrices[m][i][n];
```

I hope this helps!
- Tom